# CMS для Сообщества

Tags: php, cms, css, javascript

Хочется найти CMS, чтобы в ней были только: личные блоги, статьи и профили. Больше ничего не требуется. Чтобы ничего лишнего. И мало весила. Существует?

Юзал LS, InstantCMS - все большое, неудобное и не совсем то, что нужно. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста. Если нет - то ищу человека в крупный проект, который сможет написать этот функционал.

Comment: Хмм.. Пишите в личку.

Comment: могу взяться за написание

Comment: LS можно вычистить от лишнего или довесить нужное на их фреймворк. А вообще интересно - что посоветует уважаемый All.

Comment: Просьба откликнуться тех, кто может помочь с разработкой!
vk.com/vilkaccadm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал [instant CMS](http://www.instantcms.ru), c LiveStreet-ом проблемы, очень сложно найти исполнителя на любого вида доработки и это удручает. Но если всё хотите сами корырять, то советую посмотреть обе системы (Инстант и ЛС).

З.Ы. Увидел апдейт вопроса от ТС-а, я такой системы не встречал, скорее всего её нужно будет делать с нуля.

Comment: Проблемы с разрабами под LS имхо отчасти потому, что система слабо документирована при большом количестве "нюансов" - многое приходится искать "как" копаясь в движке. Но если пользовать на уровне адма - все доступно разжевано. Видно авторы ориентированы больше на клиентуру, чем на коммунити разработчиков.

Comment: Неоднократно сталкиваюсь с тем, что сами разработчики плагинов, не важно платный он или нет, не готовы его доработать, естественно не бесплатно, да и доработки зачастую не какие-то сверх сложные или объёмные.

+ Отдельный гемморой с шаблонами, если плагин не адаптирован под шаблон, нужно обращаться с просьбой к разработчику шаблона, чтобы он адаптировал его, он, возможно это сделает, когда будет время и предложение оплатить его работу также не спасает. 

Сам я ЛС не хочу ковырять, но готов оплатить работу, оплатить не по бросовым ценам в 5-10-15 долларов, но не могу найти исполнителя, это мра

Answer (score 0):

Вообще попробуйте [LiveStreet](http://livestreetcms.ru/)

Comment: прошу написать мне по поводу разработки движка на vk.com/vilkaccadm

Answer (score 0):

Cogear не пойдет?

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress Multi User](http://mu.wordpress.org/)?